# C++ using boolean evaluations for array positions (jump table)

Tags: c++, performance

I have a C++ IF statement which looks like (pseudo code- all variables are ints):

```
if(x < y){
    c += d;
}
else{
    c += f;
}
```

and I am thinking of trying to remove the IF statement and instead, load the values d and f into a two-element array:

```
array[0] = d
array[1] = f
```

and then I would like to be able to refer to the array elements '0' or '1' based upon the underlying type of boolean (at least in C- 0 or 1). Is there any way to do this? So my code would change to be something like:

`c += array[(x<y)]`   if this is true, c increments by f, otherwise if its false, c increments by d.

Can I do this, using the boolean result to look up the array index?

Comment: do you mean c += array[(x<y)] to match the original code.  you would have to cast the bool to a int to index I believe.  But not sure why you would want to do that.

Comment: No cast needed: `bool` to `int` is a standard conversion.

Comment: @aschepler I thought I had seen compiler warnings when doing that, but maybe I am thinking of another language.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Of course you can do it. However, chances are that you are only going to make it worse. If you think that you are removing a branch in this case — you are mistaken. Assuming a production quality compiler and x86_64 architecture, your first version will result in a nice conditional move (i.e. `cmovge`). The second version, however, will result in extra level of indirection and reading memory (i.e. `mov eax,DWORD PTR [rax*4+0x4005d0]`.

If you accept suggestions, I have a very bad feeling that you are on a very, very wrong path right now. When you are optimizing your program, you have to first **measure/profile** to determine a **bottleneck**. Only when you know what are bottlenecks, you can start optimizing them. When optimizing, you have to **measure/profile** it again to see whether there is an improvement or not. What you seem to be doing is not trusting your compiler, guessing, and doing false-optimization. I recommend you stop right there, or else it will go down the hill from there, trust me.

Answer (score 4):

You could replace the if statement with the following if you want more compact code.

```
c += (x < y) ? d : f;
```

Comment: I think this question is about optimization, not readability.

Comment: Although it parses as intended, that statement is in sore need of parentheses for clarity.

Answer (score 3):

Yes that will work. Although it will make your code harder to understand and modern compilers will eliminate the if statement anyways (when translating to assembler).

Comment: Yup- didnt make much difference although my code isn't running millions of times to check properly. May need to check the ASM instead....